# having troubles in using Slideshare API

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I have `API_Key` and `Secret_Key`. To access the API - I must provide these parameters:

```
api_key: Set this to the API Key that SlideShare has provided for you.

ts: Set this to the current time in Unix TimeStamp format, to the nearest second(?).

hash: Set this to the SHA1 hash of the concatenation of the shared secret and the timestamp (ts). i.e. SHA1 (sharedsecret + timestamp). The order of the terms in the concatenation is important.
```

I'm trying to use Slideshow Search function - I provided the required parameters in this way - but still give me error : `Failed API validation` - where's the issue ?

```
"https://www.slideshare.net/api/2/search_slideshows?api_key=API_Key&ts="+ Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000) + "&hash="+ sha1(Secret_Key + Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000)) +"&q=ionic view"
```

please confirm if this the right method to release the current time in Unix TimeStamp format in javascript

```
Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000)
```